# SELECT DISTINCT the data is distinct but not being filtered

Tags: mysql, sql, wordpress, select, distinct

Trying to track AdWords visits cause lots of click fraud.

Problem is log is overzealous so often times it will record 2 visits for 1.  This is noticable to the eye since the two `time`'s and `ip`'s are identical.  Just having trouble translating it to SQL.

**This is returning 2+ clicks for when the IP matches and the time matches.**

```
SELECT DISTINCT wmf24_statpress.time, count(ip) AS clicks, ip 
FROM wmf24_statpress
WHERE urlrequested LIKE  '%gclid=%'  
GROUP BY ip
```

Comment: There really is no point in using both a Group By clause and the Distinct keyword. Use one or the other. In this case, in order to get the Count, you need the Group By, so dump the Distinct keyword.

Comment: This is very similar to a (closed) question posted an hour ago.

Comment: This is not a real question, If you state what the input looks like and what the output **is** and what the output should be (just a few relevant snippets) **then** the question is answerable. As it stands your query is somewhat inefficient, but should work correct. And because of that you are getting the wrong answers. Voting to close.

Comment: In standard SQL, all [ungrouped columns in the SELECT list](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/group-by-hidden-columns.html) have to show up in the GROUP BY clause. MYSQL allows non-grouped columns in the SELECT list. But this is not what you want here. You want to group by time, too. Else, all identical ip will be lumped together and out of the group one time will be picked randomly.

Answer (score 2):

Just add `time` to your `GROUP BY` clause and you should be fine:

```
SELECT `time`, count(ip) AS clicks, ip 
FROM wmf24_statpress
WHERE urlrequested LIKE  '%gclid=%'  
GROUP BY `time`, ip
```

Also, you don't need the `distinct` clause

Comment: not working to be honest

Comment: My mistake, `time` is a reserved word, it should work now

Comment: @Adrian, amazingly `time` is not a reserved word, http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html  The OP just hasn't asked a fully detailed question, making it impossible to give a correct answer.

Comment: @Johan Wow... Since `time` is a data type I just assumed it was a reserved word. Go figure. I agree on the quality of the question, just upvoted your comment.

Answer (score 1):

Group by both time and ip to remove duplicates and still see repeats, i.e.

```
SELECT wmf24_statpress.time, count(ip) AS clicks, ip 
FROM wmf24_statpress
WHERE urlrequested LIKE  '%gclid=%'  
GROUP BY wmf24_statpress.time, ip
```

Comment: `DISTINCT` is shorthand for `group by -all-fields-selected-` The combination of both makes no sense; drop the distinct and the query will output exactly the same, only faster.